# Adding multiple user input to a List c#

Tags: c#, list, input

I'm trying to get user input from the user until the user enters nothing (so a enter key press) but it doesn't seem to be working properly. The user should be able to add as many numbers as they'd like and it should display them once they hit the enter key with no number entered.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Lab2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> numbersInput = new List<string>();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter an integer");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            numbersInput.Add(input);


            while (input != "")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter another integer: ");
               input = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            if (input == "")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The number you have entered is: " + " " + input);
                numbersInput.Add(input);
                foreach (string value in numbersInput)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The number that was added to the list is : " + " " + value);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a string ending in a space followed by `+ " " + input`?  It is just hard to read.  If you want two spaces, just put them both in the first string, like this: `"The number you have entered is:  " + input` (ok, I put two spaced at the end of the string but stackoverflow seems to be removing one of them.

Answer (score 3):

You're not adding anything to the `numbersInput` list except empty strings.

```
 if (input == "") // Why do anything with input if you enter this block?
 {
     Console.WriteLine("The number you have entered is: " + " " + input);
     numbersInput.Add(input);
     foreach (string value in numbersInput)
```

`numbersInput.Add(input)` needs to be in the while block instead.

Try this

```
while (input != "")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter another integer: ");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
    numbersInput.Add(input);
}

if (input == "")
{
    foreach (string value in numbersInput)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The number that was added to the list is : " + " " + value);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Edit: For summing

Change your List declaration.

```
List<int> numbersInput = new List<int>();
```

Then parse the numbers out and add them to the list. If the parsing fails, you need to handle the error.

```
while (input != "")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter another integer: ");
    input = Console.ReadLine();
    int value;
    if(!int.TryParse(input, out value))
    {
       // Error
    }
    else
    {
       numbersInput.Add(value);
    }
}
```

Then your list is no longer a string, so change the foreach

```
int sum = 0;
foreach (int value in numbersInput)
{
    sum += value;
    Console.WriteLine("The number that was added to the list is : " + " " + value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Your answer helped me the most, thank you. I hadn't realized I was adding empty strings. I'd also like to ask, how would I be able to get the sum of all of these together? I realize I'd have to convert it to int since it's a string but I'm not sure how to go upon that

Comment: @JacobNoble, see update. You will need to parse the numbers, but don't trust user input. Use `int.TryParse` to make sure it's a number and handle the error appropriately.

Comment: I'm not sure If I'm doing something wrong but I'm only getting the last number I added and not the sum of the numbers, does that make sense?

Comment: @JacobNoble, step through your code using the debugger. If you don't know how to do that, I strongly suggest looking it up. It will save you a lot of time in the future. Make sure you're declaring the sum variable outside of the foreach loop and that `numbersInput` contains the entries you're adding.

Answer (score 2):

1. Do not compare strings to "", instead use string.IsNullOrEmpty() or string.IsNullOrWhitespace() (assuming you are targeting .NET Framework 2.0 or later.)
2. You have unnecessary code (final if statement) which does not provide any value.

Aside from that, your code needs to be restructured.

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Lab2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> numbersInput = new List<string>();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter an integer: ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            {
                numbersInput.Add(input);
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter another integer: ");
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            if (numbersInput.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have entered " + numbersInput.Count + " numbers, they were: ");  
                foreach (var input in numbersInput)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t" + input);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have entered 0 numbers.");  
            }

        }
    }
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

try replace `input != ""` with `!String.IsNullOrEmpty(input)`
and `input==""` with `StringIsNullOrEmpty(input)`.

Like This:

```js
 List<string> numbersInput = new List<string>();

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter an integer");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter another integer: ");
           input = Console.ReadLine();

        }


        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The number you have entered is: " + " " + input);
           
            foreach (string value in numbersInput)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The number that was added to the list is : " + " " + value);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are NOT adding the numberInputs to the list:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        String input;
        Int32 n_In, i = 1;
        List<Int32> user_Inputs = new List<int>();

        while ((input = Console.ReadLine()).Length > 0)
            if (int.TryParse(input, out n_In)) user_Inputs.Add(n_In);

        Console.WriteLine("Numbers entered: ");
        if (user_Inputs.Count == 0) return;

        foreach (Int32 n in user_Inputs)
            Console.WriteLine("Number" + i++ + ": " + n);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Very short version, does not add your personal logic but should demonstrate the idea:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            List<string> listofstrings = new List<string> ();
            string input = null;

            while ((input = Console.ReadLine ()) != string.Empty) {
                listofstrings.Add (input);
            }
        }
    }
}
```